# Activate Active Class on Menu When On Current Page

Tags: channel-entries, segments

The code below shows all the pages in that channel active. I just want to show the page the users is on. As it is set up now all the items in the menu are .active. What am I doing wrong.

```
<div class="panel-body">
<ul class="nav nav-stacked">
{exp:channel:entries channel="{segment_1}" dynamic="no"}
<li class="{if segment_1 == "{segment_1}"}active {/if}"><a href="{comment_auto_path}/{url_title}">{title}</a></li>            
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{segment_1}" dynamic="no"}
    <li class="{if last_segment == url_title}active {/if}">
        <a href="{comment_auto_path}/{url_title}">{title}</a>
    </li> 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comparing [last_segment](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/globals/url_segments.html#last-segment) to the entries url_title should give you an accurate match. You're currently comparing to the channel or first segment, which will be the same for all the entries.